# Redirect port 80 to my home server

Tags: webserver, router, ubuntu-server

I installed Ubuntu server 16.04 on one of my computer to setup a web server. I want to install Phabricator to manage a video game project with some friends. I'm trying to configure my router (Home Hub 1000 from Bell) to redirect port 80 to this server. The problem is that it doesn't work at all. I can access to my web page from a computer on my local network with the name of the computer, but not from the outside using my IP address (the one used by my router). I added my server to DMZ and I had set up a port forwarding (Protocol: Both, Internal port: 80, External port: 80). My server use a reserved IP address configured on my router.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is similar problem when we develop our solution need integrate with cloud function by webhook approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides of a reserved local ip-address, it is useful to have a static ip-address from your provider(because they might change your ip once and a while). You can find your ip on [whatismyip.com](http://whatismyip.com)

When both port forwarding and DMZ are configured in your router, you can look if there is firewall on your server which blocks the external requests.

Comment: I know for the static IP address, but it's expansive and I don't want to pay for it.

I deactivated my firewall and I still have the problem.

Comment: It seems that the firewall and my lack of experience were the problem. My firewall blocked my resquest and I was not aware that we cannot connect to our external IP from inside our lan without using net loopback. This article helped me: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805246/cannot-access-apache-web-server-via-external-ip)